# Return features within a circle/polygon

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, wps

I am new to Openlayers and not sure if this question falls in scope of Openlayers or Geoserver. I am showing some poi data in the form of layers on  my map.

The requirement is that a user can draw a circle or a polygon anywhere on the map and I have to pull out all the POIs within this region.

I am not sure how it can be implemented. I am using createRegularPolygon to create circle or polygon, but not sure how it can fetch the features within a circle. Any inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a WPS (Web Processing Service) for this. It is available in Geoserver and there is even a Request Builder in Geoserver, see here:

[Geoserver WPS Request Builder](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/requestbuilder.html#wps-request-builder)

Here is a related question, which I think does the same thing you want to do:

[gis.stackexchange.com - Displaying Feature Info for a user defined polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28318/displaying-feature-info-for-a-user-defined-polygon)

You should post all GIS related questions there as there are more people who know answers to GIS questions.